# How can I make a random query what is sorted in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to have a mysql query that retrieve ramdon rows but in an specific order.

For exmple, I have a table with 10000 names, and want to take 10 random names in alfabetical order.

If I use order by rand() and limit together, I can have ramodon rows, but not in order. And I've also see that it's not possible to use order by rand with antoher orders by.

Right now, I'm retrieving ramdom rows and sorting the array after, but I'd like to do this in my query. It is possible? Where can I find good info about this? I was reading at mysql.com but didn't find the solution. Thanks a lot (and sorry about my poor english).

Comment: You may want to get all the rows (in any order) first and then order them alphabetically

Answer (score 0):

You could use an additional nested query for the sorting:

```
SELECT   name 
FROM     (SELECT   name
          FROM     mytable
          ORDER BY RAND()
          LIMIT    10) t 
ORDER BY name ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

like this

```
select randed.name 
from (select name 
      from user 
      order by rand() 
      limit 3
     ) randed 
order by randed.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM yourTable
    ORDER BY RAND()
    LIMIT 10) DT
ORDER BY
    Name
```